# Perform Multiple Task in ExecutorService.execute

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, executorservice

```
List<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
// add the files in the list based on some logic.           
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
for (String file : filePaths) {
    threadPool.execute(() -> {
        logImg.info(" ::::: " + Paths.get(file).getFileName());
        String boxFileId = UploadFile.uploadToBox(file, location);
        try {
            if (!boxFileId.isEmpty()){
                Files.delete(Paths.get(file));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
threadPool.shutdown();
threadPool.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

The list *filePaths* has several files. First, I log the files then upload them to an FTP server and then finally delete them from the temporary location (from where it uploaded to the FTP server).

When I ran this code initially, I got some deadlock issues. After that, I ran the same code 2-3 times and it worked fine. The number of images it uploaded to FTP was the same as the number of images it logged.

Basically, whatever files it uploads to FTP, I want to log them and then delete them from the temporary location.

The upload to FTP returns a fileId and based on that fileId we delete from the temporary location. I want to know if my code gives a guarantee that it will delete all the images it uploaded to FTP? Or if there is a possibility that it may skip some because of multiple threads?

Update 1:

I tested this over 30000 images and none of the image got uploaded. Following is the exception:

> "JMX Monitor ThreadGroup Executor Pool [Thread-2181]" Id=32712
>   daemon prio=5 TIMED_WAITING on
>   lock=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@4b3f18ab
>         Blocked (cnt): 0; Waited (cnt): 1
>         CPU nanos: 0; User nanos: 0; Bytes allocated: 568   at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: You create one task for every element in your ``filePaths`` list. As long as the execution of all the tasks doesn't eclipse your 2 hours limit at the end all tasks should be executed. Then the deletion of the files is only dependent on the condition ``!boxFileId.isEmpty()`` and the successful execution of ``Files.delete`` and that no error occurs while executing the task.

Comment: Tested with 30000 images and it's causing concurrent modification. Updated question.

Comment: There are some more questions. 1) Does the ``UploadFile.uploadToBox`` work as you expect it to work? 2) Have you tried this with one, ten , one hundred files? 3) Gets your ``filePaths`` collection somehow modified while iterating over it?

Comment: Yes. It works as expected. I tried with less number of files (3, 5) and it works fine.

Comment: Maybe your number of threads is too high? It's really hard to guess with only the few lines of code.

Comment: number of threads is 3. Maybe because it's trying to delete before the upload?

Comment: Please post your exact exception (class name and such). Also try to increase the size of your files in steps (10, 100, 1000, 10000) to test if it is just the size. And make sure you don't have duplicates in your files list. Lastly ensure that the ``Upload.uploadToBox`` method releases any file handles it holds.